# Issue from discord bot codes

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm interested to build my own discord bot and i have an issue when i tried to launch my first command, it says

**ReferenceError: Message is not defined**

Here is my code

[Lines of codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny1f4.png)

I already tried changing some codes over and over and also watching multiple videos before asking to this forum

if there's a mistake in coding this bot, please let me know and what should i do, thanks

Comment: In the future, please use [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) rather than screenshots to share code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 9, you wrote `Message` (spelled with a capital M). JavaScript variables **are case sensitive**, meaning that `Message` and `message` can be two different things.

Try changing that line to:

```js
if (message.channel.type !== 'text') return;
```